# Calling microservice using feign client from Zuul gateway filter

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, feign

I have a validation service which needs to be called before every request, and if the validation fails I want to return the result from gateway itselh,so I am trying to call it using feign-client from my Zuul gateway filter. It is giving me some exception and not able to make the call

I have tried creating a proxy of my service to be called and enabled it as a fegin client.

Run method of my Zuul filter. This filter is of type "pre"

```
        @Autowired
    private ValidationServiceProxy proxy;


        public Object run()  {

            try {

            RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();


            HttpServletRequest request =ctx.getRequest();


        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("interaction_id", "1000");

        String responseEntity= proxy.test(request);

        logger.info("Response"+responseEntity);


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

My validation service proxy code

```
    @FeignClient(name="validation-service")
    public interface ValidationServiceProxy {


    @GetMapping("/api/v1/test")
    public String test(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest);

        }
```

My controller code on the validation service.

```
      @GetMapping(value = "/test")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public ResponseEntity<String> test(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

    String result = "Hello World";

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);

}




    feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write JSON: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false) (through reference chain: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.Servlet30RequestWrapper["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["asyncContext"])
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildEncodedTemplateFromArgs.resolve(ReflectiveFeign.java:376)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildTemplateByResolvingArgs.create(ReflectiveFeign.java:224)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:74)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy162.test(Unknown Source)
        at com.in28minutes.microservices.netflixzuulapigatewayserver.ZuulLoggingFilter.run(ZuulLoggingFilter.java:48)
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.preRoute(FilterProcessor.java:133)
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.preRoute(ZuulRunner.java:105)
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.preRoute(ZuulServlet.java:125)
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false) (through reference chain: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.Servlet30RequestWrapper["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["asyncContext"])
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:296)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder.encode(SpringEncoder.java:112)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildEncodedTemplateFromArgs.resolve(ReflectiveFeign.java:372)
        ... 74 more
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false) (through reference chain: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.Servlet30RequestWrapper["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["asyncContext"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287)
        ... 78 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getAsyncContext(Request.java:1784)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getAsyncContext(RequestFacade.java:1068)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
        ... 87 more
```

Answer (score 1):

See the below code. after adding the zuul. uri becomes like this
http://zuul-service/your-service/uri
That how you need to change the proxy interface.

```
@FeignClient(name="zuul-service")
public interface ValidationServiceProxy {


@GetMapping("validation-service/api/v1/test")
public String test(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest);

    }
```